# The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

There was a machine running Windows Server 2008. It was a domain controller. Years passed and another machine running Windows Server 2008 was added to the domain as a secondary domain controller. A few more years passed and eventually the primary failed and the secondary took control-ish. Now when I try accessing the server manager I get these kinds of errors.

```
The specified domain controller could not be contacted. This affects the following domain in the console:

 Domain: mydomain.domain

The error was:
  The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

Please choose from the following options:
  [x] Chose a different domain controller
  [ ] Retry
  [ ] Remove this domain from the console
```

**I have the impression that I must now promote my secondary domain controller to a primary domain controller.

Is this true? Where can I find instructions on how to do this?**

Comment: Modern Active Directory does not have a concept of a secondary or primary domain controller.

Comment: You may need to seize the infrastructure master roles, however. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816779%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Make sure to delete any dns records for your old server. My guess is both servers ip address is registered at mydomain.domain